# Must app be tested for all iphone sizes for approval

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

am newbie in iOS app development.
say, I have created an iOS Swift 3.0 App for iphone 6/6+ (7/7+) 
I build Swift app for iphone 6/6+ (same as 7/7+). This means I use the standard Screen size 375x667 to start with.

In Xcode 8.2.1, there is a list of Devices from iPad to iphone 4s which you can use to test to see how your app fit into the targeted devices.

1) I started on iphone 6 (same as iphone 7), my app fit in and look good for this screen size. When I tested it on iphone 4, my App wont fit in; some UI control like TextView is missing. Must I fit my app for this iphone 4s?

2) The same app can fit in ipad (pro 9.7, 12.9 inch) but the UI control will look small.

I need your help for the following questions for app store submission.

a) It is a must that my app must fit in for all the screen size such as ipad and iphone 4s when I started out the app on iphone 6 or 7?

b) Can I just target iphone 6 and above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit setting to target only the iPhone6 and above, rather Apple will frown over this and would not encourage it.

But by doing the following, you can target only iPhone5 and above.

1. In the Project --> Target --> General --> Set the targeted devices only to iPhone instead of iPad/Universal.
2. Again in, Project --> Target --> General --> Set the deployment target to iOS 10.0.

As iOS 10 does not support iPhone 4s and previous devices you can get away with this.

Also, iOS 10 adoption is already about 80% as reported on Jan 4th, 2017. So you are already targeting most of the users.

Comment: I find that to design a page to fit in all screen sizes is a challenge even though I am using AutoLayout. To squeeze everything in one page will not make the page look nice. I need your confirmation, can I use Long Scrollview say 1000 height for ViewController.Is this allowed?

Comment: This will help to design for iphone 5 and 4s when I have some UI to put in view controller.

Comment: @MilkBottle Yes its a challenge and has a learning curve. But over time (maybe over the course of your first application) you get the hold of auto-layout and design for multiple resolutions. Regarding the scrollview, you can put as much content in it as you want and increase its height, there are no restrictions. For starters, I recommend you watch WWDC apple autolayout video. It will help.